# MOSS to have a certain page available in all sites

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a MOSS Publishing Site, say it's http://dev. It's basically a magazine site, with an issue for every month, so it's dev/2011-01, dev/2011-02, and so on.

There are some general pages like About.aspx, ContactUs.aspx which should be available for all issues. I don't want to create these pages in every issue/site. I know we can put the page in TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS folder.

But I don't really like it, because I want the pages to reside in dev/Pages folder, so it's in 1 repository, instead of here and there.

Is there any other way to achieve this? Like a custom handler that will direct request from dev/2011-01/Pages/About.aspx to dev/Pages/About.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always write a `HttpHandler` which will redirect the request for these pages.

However , the best way would be to

- Put these pages in a feature
- Deploy the feature using `Module` Feature with `GhostableInLibrary=TRUE`
- Activate the feature on all magazine sites.

This way, your pages will reside on file system in feature folder, but will be visible on all sites as ghosted files. You can upgrade the feature to upgrade the files.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried, but found error. My elements.xml is like below

<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

  <Module Name="GeneralPages" Url="About.aspx">

    <File Path="About.aspx" Url="About.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary"></File>

  </Module>

</Elements>


It says Failed to instantiate file "About.aspx" from module "GeneralPages": Source path "About.aspx" not found.

Comment: I cant tell anything from this. I need to know structure of feature fiels and aspx files.. Post a new question for this

Comment: I've created a new question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967485/moss-how-to-use-feature-to-propagate-pages-in-root-site-to-child-sites.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would need a custom handler. Either you are leveraging the navigation, which means these pages exist on every subsite, or you are manually entering the URL. If it is the latter, why not point to the URL on the root site?

When I've done something like this in the past, I create a custom master page and add the URLs to the pages in the root site in either the left nav or footer (or both). You should be able to use a URL in the style of: `~sitecollection/Pages/About.aspx`