# MOSS how to use feature to propagate pages in root site to child sites

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a publishing site, say http://dev. I've created a page called About.aspx, so the url would be http://dev/Pages/About.aspx. I'd like to use Feature so that the About.aspx page is available when users access it from the child sites, for example: [http]://dev/2010-01/Pages/About.aspx, [http]://dev/2010-02/Pages/About.aspx, and so on, without having to copy the About.aspx to each site.

Answer (score 0):

Have these sites already been created? If not you could create your own site definition and add it using a module

```
<Module Name="AboutPage" Url="Pages" RootWebOnly="FALSE">
   <File Url="About.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" />
</Module>
```

Comment: You could also put that exact same module into a Feature and activate it on every subsite.

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry for late reply. But I think the About.aspx must be located in the feature folder right? Which must be a stand alone aspx file. Problem is, I already have the page inside my SharePoint root web Pages folder as I mentioned, dev/Pages/About.aspx. I can't take out the page and copy it to feature folder as I need to reference a master page in _catalogs/mag/MyMaster.master.

Comment: Are you using any of the static tokens when referencing the Master Page?

`~site/default.master` and `~sitecollection/default.master`

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476046%28v=office.12%29.aspx